# I'm a noob at ubuntu and linux need help

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, skype

every time I try to update anything or install any program onto my computer like skype and simple things, I cannot find them like in the tutorials. I can see they have downloaded but I can not find them anywhere. everytime I update this error comes up

```
Duplicate sources.list entry http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ trusty/partner i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.canonical.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty_partner_binary-i386_Packages)
```

and I don't have any idea what it means.
I love linux and i play world of warcraft on it because I prefer the os it is smoother and lighter than Windows.
I just need to know how to fix the error that comes up every time I `sudo apt-get update` and if anyone has any ideas about the programs not being visible then that would be amazing!!! cause quite frankly it really upsets me that it just stopped working all of the sudden. I have been bragging everything up about Ubuntu and linux and I can't even get my computer to run programs....

I apologize ahead of time if this is just a simple fix and it take 2 minutes but I want to thank everyone ahead of time for the help!

edit sorcelist

Comment: are you running 64 bit?

Comment: Can you post the contents of your sources.list file for further investigation?

Comment: yes i am running 64 bit

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to fix duplicate items in your source list, which is really just a big config file with URLs in it..(kinda) and you have two in there that are the same.

Open software sources, uncheck "Canonical Partners". The Conflict is between "Canonical Partners" and " Canonical partners Added by software Center"

Also if you need skype you can download it from their site, but you can also use it on the web as well if you don't want to deal with download it.  I think live.com allows use of it depending on your needs.  Also if you just want to video chat with friends are great service exists for free which is faster then Skype.

https://meet.jit.si/

It is similar to hangouts and doesn't require you to install anything.